# Clean local OSM website database but only the geographical data

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

I also posted this question at help.openstreetmap 2 weeks ago but got no answer, so I hope someone here have the answer.

I ran ./osmosis --truncate-apidb in my local OSM website to clean the data, so I could import new geofabrik data, and it worked perfectly.

But I noticed that, beyond the geospatial data, I wiped also the users accounts, iD configuration, and I think even the pre-rendered tiles were gone, because I feel the rendering is slower now.

So, there is a way to clean only the spatial data?

Comment: original question: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/73653/clean-local-osm-website-database-but-only-the-geographical-data

Comment: You can truncate the changeset table with casdading, this will retain everything except for changesets, nodes, ways and relations.

Comment: thanks mmd, can you post it as an answer to be accepted?